# My rewrite rule isn't working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I currently want my site to rewrite from

```
.com/page/1234
```

to

```
.com/?view=page&id=1234
```

Heres my .htaccess content:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/page/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?view=page&id=$1

ErrorDocument 404 errors/404.html
```

When I type ".com/page/1" my site just redirects to the 404 page. 
What have I done wrong? I tried to the simplest:

```
RewriteRule ^/page$ /about.php
```

But it doesn't work either. So I'm having some suspect that 000webhost (my current host) is not supporting RewriteRule although they stated they support it.

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience, I know they -do- support `RewriteRule`, but it is somewhat horrible to test them. In "per-directory"-context, the slash from a directory is appended to the "prefix" part of the url. `.htaccess` always works as in "per-directory"-context. A `RewriteRule` that begins with a slash in `.htaccess` will therefore never match anything.

If you change your `.htaccess` to the following, everything should work as expected:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?view=page&id=$1

ErrorDocument 404 errors/404.html
```

I recommend reading [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for `mod_rewrite`. It contains a lot of useful information.

Comment: It didn't work. It didn't redirected to 404 either. I have to add a slash before errors/404.html to have it redirected correctly. I still can't figure a way around the rule.